# What is the procedure to install StyleCop?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, visual-studio-express, stylecop

I am trying to install StyleCop, but I am unable to install it. After installation I couldn't see StyleCop in my code. If anyone find please help me regarding this.

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't see stylecop in my code"? Have a look here http://www.thereforesystems.com/stylecop-tutorial/

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using, and which edition? Express?

Comment: Yes I have gone through that.Right now I am working on visual c# 2010 Express,I am not finding stylecop.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using VS Express you won't see it, as VS Express only supports a limited number of plugins. You *may* be able to run it manually by hacking the solution file via [MSBuild integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/24/source-analysis-msbuild-integration.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After you installed StyleCop, open Visual Studio, right click on a project or a solution and hit `Run StyleCop` menu item.

Comment: Do you see StyleCop in the `Tools` menu?